What are some hypothetical pathways for generating ATP from glucose under anaerobic conditions?
I am very confused about how the steps of glycolysis relate to the generation of energy. From basic descriptions of metabolism, I would've thought that after opening the ring structure, the glucose might lose one oxygen or carbon at a time, and that these reaction would be coupled to the formation of energy carriers like ATP.
Instead, a lot of the steps involve rearrangement, and step 4 breaks glucose down without making any energy carrier. Steps 6 and 7 seem like a phosphate group is transferred on by having that reaction coupled to an electron transfer, and then the phosphate group is immediately taken off. This makes me think that maybe the glucose derivates are special (as compared to derivates of other plausible energy storage molecules) because they have electrons that really want to leave the molecule.
I’ve tried reading textbooks and looking a lot of different things up, but I feel like I’m not getting closer to understanding. I think an answer to these questions would be helpful:
What would be the most straightforward way for glucose to generate ATP in anaerobic conditions? If you had at your disposal any chemicals that a cell does, and you could create an enzyme that could lower the activation energy of any of your desired reactions*, what would you do to create one molecule of ATP from glucose with the fewest number of reactions? And, what is a series of reactions that uses the smallest amount of glucose’s energy to generate ATP? I’m curious if these sets of reactions will share the characteristics I’ve noted of glycolysis from above.
*I am assuming that the abilities of enzymes are not what constrains the evolution of metabolism, but maybe I am totally off.
Thank you in advance!

Welcome to SE Biology. Please finish the [Tour] and read the Help on asking questions. This is a Question and Answer site, not a discussion site and hypothetical questions are generally off-topic. If you do not understand the rationale for energy generation in metabolism, it is fine to explain precisely what your problem is and ask us if we can clarify. Assuming that it is somehow “wrong” and asking us to play God seems arrogant on your part and assumes arrogance on ours, even though I am sure that this was not intended.
